# How can I set a specific provider for a source in Xorg

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr, amdgpu, xorg.conf

I have a fresh Ubuntu install with two GPUs (the integrated Vega GPU and a Radeon RX 570). My primary monitor is connected to my graphics card, and my secondary monitor on the left is connected to the integrated GPU. With this setup, I'm not able to use my secondary monitor, it remains blank.

The BIOS setup is okay, both GPUs are enabled, and my Windows OS is working fine.

So far, I came up with a temporary solution using xrandr, which are these two commands:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --auto --output HDMI-A-1-1 --auto --left-of HDMI-A-0
```

With this I can solve my problem for this session, but I want to persist it in my xorg.conf, but I haven't found anything related to that in any forum, and I'm not an expert in xorg configuring.

I found answers suggesting to add these two commands to an Xsession.d script or my .xinitrc, but honestly, I don't want this to be a dirty solution, I want it permanently persisted in my xorg.conf, plus it's difficult to me to work with xrandr during init scripts because I have to manually sleep before and between commands, and that makes it even dirtier.